# resize MLMultiArray(512,512) to MLMultiArray (512,512,18) in swift coreml

Tags: arrays, swift, coreml

I have an `MLMultiArray` with the shape of (512,512) the `dataType` is `Double32` and the elements varies from 0 to 17 let's call it ***parse***. Now I want to reshape my `MLMultiArray` to (512,512,18) in a way that each number represent the third dimension. for example if element (20,20) is equal to 4, in the new `MLMultiArray` I will have (20,20,4) equal to 1.

The python code for this would be:

```
for i in range(18):
    result[:, :, i][np.where(parse == i)] = 1
```

Now I want an equivalent optimised swift code with above explanation.

Comment: Try doing it via python code and convert it via coremltools.

Comment: @DmytroHrebeniuk I should do this at the runtime is there a way to it at the run time